# .Net Core 3.1 - Encoding process output

Tags: c#, encoding, .net-core-3.1

I have a process which executes some commands like a ping. The output give me the result in French but it is not well encoded.
For exemple, I get

```
Envoi d'une requˆte 'ping'
```

instead of

```
Envoi d'une requête 'ping'
```

I read that there are some encodings which are not available with .Net Core but can be added with the Encoding.CodePage library. So I tried it in my project.

I started to add in the App.xaml.cs :

```
private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
   Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
}
```

Then in my function which manage the process, I get the good encoding :

```
var enc1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = enc1252;
```

However it doesn't work, the output result is the same and when I check the object 'enc1252' I can see many errors in the properties like :

> enc1252.BodyName threw an exception of type
> 'System.NotSupportedException'

Is there something I did wrong or I missed ?

Comment: The encoding provider does not support all properties, eg BodyName. That is not a problem and it works correctly when used in the Process class. Maybe your process uses another encoding? Try CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage. Other common used code pages are 437 and 850.

Comment: Maybe the problem ist not the encoding, but the font that displays the text. Did you try different fonts?

Comment: @pschill It works with the cultureInfo. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding provider does not support all properties, e. g. `BodyName`. However, it should still work correctly when used in the `Process` class.

The process probably uses another encoding, for example:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage
```